# How to set <body> tag ID to <select> value with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, select

I’m working on a Lightmode/Darkmode selector for my website. I can't figure out how to set the body tag to the value of a select element.

So far, here's what I have.

```
<body>
  <select name="ld" id="ld">
    <option value="normal" selected >Light mode</option>
    <option value="darkmode" >Dark mode</option>
  </select>
</body>
```

and the CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

#darkmode {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `id` selector for this, use a class instead, and [change the class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) of `body`.

Comment: you need js to help you assign the selected value of <select> to the <body>

Comment: Use the [`change` event](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event). `document.getElementById("ld").addEventListener("change", ({ target: { value } }) => document.body.classList = value);` is one solution.